# В каком стандарте появилась функция to_string?

Tags: c++

у меня старенький компилятор (C++98). функция to_string() присутствует в библиотеке но во время компиляции выдает ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Фкнкция `std::to_string` была включена в стандарт `C++ 2011`. В связи с этим, например, в `MS VS 2010` она перегружена не для всех целочисленных типов, для которых она должна быть перегружена в соответствии со стандартом, потому что компилятор `MS VC++ 2010` вышел до окончательного принятия стандарта.
Об этом недостатке `MS VC++ 2010` можете почитать в моем сообщении по этой [ссылке](http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-40-00000042-000-0-0-1343495263)

Comment: у меня как раз такой недоделанный компилятор. спасибо.

Comment: @perfect  В таком случае вам надо делать явный кастинг аргумента к тому типу, для которого функция определена в MS VC++ 2010.

Comment: спасибо с кастингом заработало

Comment: @perfect, только, если функции должны быть, то лучше их и реализовать где-то в одном месте, а не забивать весь код кастами. А при переходе на более новый компилятор, просто тот фай из построения исключить. Не уверен, можно ли проверить версию компилятора в директивах типа #if, но если можно, то стоит этим и воспользоваться.